# Search entire html document for an exact code "<br>foo<br>" and delete it

Tags: php, javascript, regex, string, replace

I have a page which has exactly `<br>foo<br>` several times in different parts of its code

**Example:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    The quick brown <br>foo<br> fox jumped over the lazy <br>foo<br> dog.
  </body>
</html>
```

**But I need the page to say:** 
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.

**Rather than:**
The quick brown
foo
fox jumped over the lazy
foo
dog.

I need it to keep deleting the `<br>foo<br>` even if I later add more text and more `<br>foo<br>`

Please provide a full functional code, hopefully php

**Additional information:**
I am loading much of the text through php includes.
I don't want to have to declare the original string in php, I want the php to check the html code and delete a specified string.

Comment: You could do a naive `str_replace()` if you wanted.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What do you mean by "even if I add more text..."?  Are you loading additional content via ajax?

Comment: @kbad, I have tried css `visibility:hidden;`, but I don't even want that string in the code. @alex The issue with `str_replace()` is that I don't want to have to declare the original string in php, I want the php to check the html code and delete a specified string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do what you're asking with PHP unless the string is being output by PHP...

I suppose you could use javascript for this; for example (using JQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var old_body = $('body').html();
        var new_body = old_body.replace(new RegExp("<br>foo<br>", "g"),'');
        $('body').html(new_body);
    });
```

However, it really would be better if you used one of the methods described already and pass the content through PHP.

Updated to actually work...

Answer (score 0):

Use [`str_replace`](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
str_replace('<br>foo<br>','',$textInHere);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with PHP, but it seems that this would work:

```
str_replace ( "<br>foo<br>", "" , a string containing your html document)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$your_html = 'The quick brown <br>foo<br> fox jumped over the lazy <br>foo<br> dog.';
$your_html = preg_replace("/<br>foo<br>/", "", $your_html);
echo $your_html;
```

[working demo](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/ead17.php)

Comment: Genesis, Thanks for the quick reply, but I don't want to have to declare the original string in php, I want the php to check the html code and delete a specified string.

Answer (score 0):

If you load the file into a string in php, you can do:

```
$cleaned = str_replace("<br>foo<br>", "", $raw);
```